# Is there any method to append this three array?

Tags: python, arrays

Now, I have three arrays but I cannot insert these in one array.

```
x = [63.001359127617185, 21.02926724707507, -64.99968875087593, 65.00084778093242, 34.00056603763737]
y = [-35.998640872382815, 5.029267247075071, -23.99968875087593, -78.99915221906758, -98.99943396236263]
z = [0.002285667282364421, 0.060360611442703896, 0.0008887456442498822, 0.007301422400429866, 0.004970329828018857]
```

My target is

```
array([[63.001359127617185,  -35.998640872382815,  0.002285667282364421],
     [21.02926724707507,  5.029267247075071,   0.060360611442703896],
     [-64.99968875087593, -23.99968875087593, 0.0008887456442498822],
     [65.00084778093242,  -78.99915221906758,  0.007301422400429866],
     [34.00056603763737,  -98.99943396236263,   0.004970329828018857]])
```

This is my attempt but it arrange in row.

```
np_arr = np.array([X,Y,Z])
print(np_arr)
```

Is there any way to merge these in one array as a column following my target? Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To merge the arrays as columns, you can use the np.column_stack() function in NumPy

```
import numpy as np
x = [63.001359127617185, 21.02926724707507, -64.99968875087593, 65.00084778093242, 34.00056603763737]
y = [-35.998640872382815, 5.029267247075071, -23.99968875087593, -78.99915221906758, -98.99943396236263]
z = [0.002285667282364421, 0.060360611442703896, 0.0008887456442498822, 0.007301422400429866, 0.004970329828018857]
merged_array = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
print(merged_array)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that simply using

```
result = [[xi, yi, zi] for xi, yi, zi in zip(x, y, z)]
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just make a new array and append them

```
arr = []
arr.append(x)
arr.append(y)
arr.append(z)
print(arr)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output and is not a numpy array (although this wasn't implicitly stated in the question. Still, this puts the arrays as rows while the question asks for columns...)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).